# Run alembic migrations on a flask elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, alembic

I have an elastic beanstalk instance with flask installed. I have alembic properly setup and I can run the command locally by running

```
cd migrations
alembic upgrade head
```

I made a file in my .ebextensions which looks like this:

```
container_commands:
  00-run-alembic:
    command: alembic upgrade head
```

But it's not working, I know i probably need to cd in to the proper dir, but im not sure where to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify working directory for that command, e.g.:

```
container_commands:
  00-run-alembic:
    command: alembic upgrade head
    cwd: /put/your/directory/here
```

Comment: For elastic beanstalk instances, the directory will probably be something like `/var/app/current`.